# Homeomorphism and Lebesgue measure problem

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Let $\mu$ be the Lebesgue measure. Show that if $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a homeomorphism and $\mu(D)=0 \implies \mu(f(D))=0$ then $f(E)$ is measurable for all Lebesgue measurable $E$.

Attempt: Since $E$ is Lebesgue measurable $E= B \cup N$ for some borel set $B$ and null set $N$. Since a homeomorphism maps null sets to null sets, and $(f^{-1})^{-1}(E)=f(E)$ for all $E$, we have that $f(E)=f(B) \cup f(N)$ which is the union of a borel set and null set. Thus, $f(E)$ is Lebesgue measurable. If this proof is really this simple, I suppose I should prove $f$ maps borel sets to borel sets. Any suggestions? I posted this question some time ago and was given a hint. I reattempted the problem and I am wondering if it is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct. As $f$ is a homeomorphism, it sends open sets to open sets. And since Borel sets are precisely the $\sigma$-algebra generated by open sets, $f$ sends Borel sets to Borel Sets.